# How can I show the video on jsp by getting from database?

Tags: java, jsp

I currently doing an function which is to display the video on the jsp. I am saving the video in **BLOB** format. After getting the video in the **byte[]** format I want to show the video on the jsp. I used the `<video>` but the video is not able to play.

How can I achieve this? Can anyone please suggest with a small example?

In jsp return an url :

```
<video id="addVideo" controls autoplay>
    <source src="${videoUrl}" />
</video>
```

From the controller I return the Url as:

```
byte[]  v_byte = (getting from the data base)
String videoUrl = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(v_byte);
model.addAttribute("videoUrl ",videoUrl );
```

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: What's the video size? Do you need streaming and what about resuming? What's the video format?

Comment: @DaniloMuñoz format of the video is Mp4. Streaming resuming woud be better. but for now I need to play the video fist. Actually I am dispaying list of video by taking it on a pop up.

Comment: @DaniloMuñoz  video size is 1 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code for video/mp4 video:

```
    byte[]  v_byte = (getting from the data base)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("data:video/mp4;base64,");
sb.append(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.encodeBase64(v_byte, false)));
String videoUrl = sb.toString();
    model.addAttribute("videoUrl",videoUrl );
```

Comment: Compilation error showing that StringUtils.newStringUtf8(byte[]) not defined. Can you please provide the package of StringUtils

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils, add commons-lang.jar to your build path.

Comment: I already use that package. I configure this jar file but still I am getting the compilation error.

Comment: Can you try with this Class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils! commons-codec.jar

Comment: Thanks buddy... it worked. solved the issue. That method is in Commons codec package.