# How to plugin video in background to my website?

Tags: jsp

I am working on spring and I am trying to add video in background to my website. so anyone can help me? how to plugin video in background to my JSP page?

Comment: if you can mix it with html here's a good [blog](https://slicejack.com/fullscreen-html5-video-background-css/) on how to do it, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32999360/2650584) could also give you a good start

Comment: yeah, I have used video tag and Iframe also.